# Can I add a vector of five numbers as an input in shiny app R

Tags: r, shiny

It might be a silly question but troubles me for long.
I have a parameter that I call "bc" which is a vector of five numbers:
e.g., `bc=c(1,2,3,4,5)`

I would like to put a sliderInput with which I can choose five different numbers for bc
that all have the same distance, e.g., `bc=c(2,3,4,5,6) or bc=c(3,4,5,6,7)`

Q1: Is that possible, to put a vector of five numbers as an input?

Here is my try:

```
sliderInput("bc", label = "trade-off", max=10, min = 1,
                        value = c(1,2),step = 1))
```

This is not what I want, but as far as I can get.

Q2: if there is a way to change numbers of "bc" how can I add it to the reactive?

This is what I tried, but it does not work and does not make sense.

```
bc=as.numeric(strsplit(input$bc,","))
```

Any help is highly appreciated since I am really stuck.

Comment: read in one number in the `sliderInput` and then create `bc=c(bcn:(bcn+5))`, where `bcn = as.numeric(input$bc)`.

Comment: That's a good tip. Thanks for spending time on this. I appreciate. Have a nice day